# Apigee BaaS expired token

Tags: usergrid, apigee-baas

I have an app with several users who log in on a regular basis to do Q/A on my data. Every single one of them can no longer log into the app. When they attempt to log in they are getting an expired token error. Here is my code:

```
client_creds = { orgName: "org", appName: "app" };

dataClient = new Apigee.Client( client_creds );

dataClient.login( username, password, function (error,response) {            
    if (error) {
        //error — could not log user in
        alert( error.message );
    } else {
        //success — user has been logged in
        token = dataClient.token;
        initializeUI();
    }
} );
```

I don't know if users are actually logging out or not. In any case why are users getting an expired token error? How can the token get refreshed on login?

Comment: Are you storing the token indenfinitly? By default, it has a 3600s expiry. You may want to increase it?

Comment: If it's set by default to 3600s expiry then it stands to reason that there is a mechanism in place to refresh it. Otherwise, every 3600s users would need to create a new login or manually remove the token from local storage. Am I am missing something?

Comment: There are no refresh tokens in Usergrid (unfortunately). You can increase the expiry, but yes, your assumption of the way to work around it is correct.

Comment: Many thanks. My solution is to set expiry to never - even though that is sub-optimal.

Comment: I always end up doing the same, and I agree. Just make sure you invalidate the token on log out.